# get Network speed to a specific network in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile

I would like to know the network speed for a specific network without connecting to it.
I have the SSID and the password and would like to know what's the network speed and availability. is it possible?

EDIT

actually possible through:

Registering the app as Hotspot helper. (forums.developer.apple.com/message/30657#30657)

```
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>

for(NEHotspotNetwork *hotspotNetwork in [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]) {
    NSString *ssid = hotspotNetwork.SSID;
    NSString *bssid = hotspotNetwork.BSSID;
    BOOL secure = hotspotNetwork.secure;
    BOOL autoJoined = hotspotNetwork.autoJoined;
    double signalStrength = hotspotNetwork.signalStrength; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot determine network speed if you are not connected to the network.